# I'm trying to print the created date for specific files in the format 1/1/2021. I'm using python in spyder 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, date-format

I have been printing out file names and file paths for work, but I also need to print the dates(created date).  Here is the code I have so far:

```
# import os and time modules
import os, time

#root directory to print from
rootdir = (r'D:\Projects\EoF\WetlandSiting\Maps')

#get created date (ctime)
#c_time = os.path.getctime(rootdir)
#local_time = time.ctime(c_time)

#walk through directories and print specific files
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".asc"):# or file.endswith(".img") or file.endswith(".tif") or 
file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".shp"):
        print(os.path.join(file))            
        print(os.path.join(subdir))
#print(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file)))
```

I add and remove #'s to use what I need when I need it.

Here is the error I get:

File "D:\directory\PrintFilesFromMultSubdirs_withTime2.py", line 25, in 
print(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file)))

File "C:\directory\genericpath.py", line 65, in getctime
return os.stat(filename).st_ctime

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'dd65_dem_asc.asc'

**I then added join:
print(time.ctime(os.path.join.getctime(file)))**

**but this gave me a separate error:**

runfile('D:/directory/Scripts/GISorganization')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\directory\PrintFilesFromMultSubdirs_withTime2.py", line 25, in 
print(time.ctime(os.path.join.getctime(file)))

**AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getctime'**

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Thank you!
James

Comment: You should show us your current format.

Comment: Would you also be able to tell us your end goal for this project as well so we could better understand the context of your question?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis I'm not sure what you mean.  Sorry, I'm very new to this.

Comment: @tdelozie My end goal is to have a catalog in Excel of our GIS library data.  There are multiple fields that I need to print out in python, then copy and paste into Excel.  Three of these fields are: FileName, FilePath, and date in the format of 1/1/2021.